# keep all selected values after submit

Tags: form-submit, cascadingdropdown

I'm stuck with this script I'm using:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="includes/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="includes/css/wt-gallery.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/configuratie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery.wt-gallery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wait_1').hide();
    $('#drop_1').change(function(){
      $('#wait_1').show();
      $('#result_1').hide();
      $.get("func.php", {
        func: "drop_1",
        drop_var: $('#drop_1').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_1').fadeOut();
        setTimeout("finishAjax('result_1', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
    $('#wait_2').hide();
    $('#drop_2').change(function(){
      $('#wait_2').show();
      $('#result_2').hide();
      $.get("func.php", {
        func: "drop_2",
        drop_var: $('#drop_2').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_2').fadeOut();
        setTimeout("finishAjax2('result_2', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
    $('#wait_3').hide();
    $('#drop_3').change(function(){
      $('#wait_3').show();
      $('#result_3').hide();
      $.get("func.php", {
        func: "drop_3",
        drop_var: $('#drop_3').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_3').fadeOut();
        setTimeout("finishAjax3('result_3', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
});

function finishAjax(id, response) {
  $('#wait_1').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
function finishAjax2(id, response) {
  $('#wait_2').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
function finishAjax3(id, response) {
  $('#wait_3').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}

function finishAjax_tier_three(id, response) {
  $('#wait_2').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
function finishAjax_tier_four(id, response) {
  $('#wait_3').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
function finishAjax_tier_five(id, response) {
  $('#wait_4').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
</script>
        </head>
<?php
$website = "it";
    // configuratie file en db connect
include "includes/inc/config.inc.php";
include('db.php');
include_once "class/slider.class.php";
include('func.php');
$slideralbum = new slideralbum($dbo);
$sliders = $slideralbum->getSliderItems($website);
?>
<body>
<p>
<form name="product" action="" method="post">

    <select name="drop_1" id="drop_1">

      <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Selecteer Merk</option>

      <?php getTierOne(); ?>

    </select> 

    <span id="wait_1" style="display: none;">
    <img alt="Please Wait" src="ajax-loader.gif"/>
    </span>
    <span id="result_1" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span id="wait_2" style="display: none;">
    <img alt="Please Wait" src="ajax-loader.gif"/>
    </span>
    <span id="result_2" style="display: none;"></span> 
    <span id="wait_3" style="display: none;">
    <img alt="Please Wait" src="ajax-loader.gif"/>
    </span>
    <span id="result_3" style="display: none;"></span> 
    <span id="wait_4" style="display: none;">
    <img alt="Please Wait" src="ajax-loader.gif"/>
    </span>
    <span id="result_4" style="display: none;"></span> 
  <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Refresh" onclick='location.reload()'>
</form>
</p>
<p>
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $drop = $_POST['drop_1'];
    $drop_2 = $_POST['drop_2'];
    $drop_3 = $_POST['drop_3'];
    $drop_4 = $_POST['drop_4'];
    $drop_5 = $_POST['drop_5'];
?>
<table border="1" bordercolor="#B5B5B5" style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="250" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
        <td>Merk:</td>
        <td><?php echo $drop;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Model:</td>
        <td><?php echo $drop_2;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bouwjaar:</td>
        <td><?php echo $drop_3;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Kleur:</td>
        <td><?php echo $drop_4;?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
<div id="banner-block">       <!-- Begin of Slideshow -->
    <div class="container">          
        <div class="wt-gallery" style="width:920px; height:375px;">
            <div class="main-screen">
                                <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $drop = $_POST['drop_1'];
    $drop_2 = $_POST['drop_2'];
    $drop_3 = $_POST['drop_3'];
    $drop_4 = $_POST['drop_4'];
    $drop_5 = $_POST['drop_5'];
?>
                    <img src="images/<?php echo $drop_5;?>" alt="<?php echo $drop_5;?>" width="920" height="360"/>
<?php
                    }
?>
                <noscript>
                <!-- placeholder image when javascript is off -->
                <img src="../images/triworks_abstract27.jpg" alt=""/>
                </noscript>
            </div>
            <div class="cpanel">
            <div class="thumbs-back"></div>                        
                <div class="thumbnails">
                    <ul>
<?php $sliders = $slideralbum->getSliderItems($website, NULL);
foreach($sliders as $slider){
?> 
                        <li effect="none">
                    <div>
                        <a href="<?php echo $slider->slider_img; ?>" height="360" width="720" alt="<?php echo $slider->slider_img; ?>" />
                        <img src="<?php echo $slider->slider_tmb; ?>" height="70" width="125" alt="<?php echo $slider->slider_tmb; ?>" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="data">    
                    </div>
                        </li>
<?php
}
?>  
                    </ul>
                </div>          
            <div class="thumbs-fwd"></div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

func.php

```
<?php
//**************************************
//     Page load dropdown results     //
//**************************************
function getTierOne()
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT make FROM vehicles ORDER BY make ASC") 
    or die(mysql_error());

      while($tier = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 

        {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $tier['make'];?>"<?php echo (isset($_POST['drop_1']) && $_POST['drop_1'] == $tier['make']) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ; ?>><?php echo $tier['make'];?></option>
<?php

        }

}

//**************************************
//     First selection results     //
//**************************************
if (isset($_GET['func'])&& $_GET['func'] == "drop_1" ) {
drop_1($_GET['drop_var']);
}

function drop_1($drop_var)
{  
    include_once('db.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT model FROM vehicles WHERE make='$drop_var' ORDER BY model") 
    or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<select name="drop_2" id="drop_2">
          <option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Selecteer Model</option>';

           while($drop_2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_2['model'].'">'.$drop_2['model'].'</option>';
            }

    echo '</select>';
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$('#wait_2').hide();
    $('#drop_2').change(function(){
      $('#wait_2').show();
      $('#result_2').hide();
      $.get(\"func.php\", {
        func: \"drop_2\",
        drop_var: $('#drop_1').val(),
        drop_var2: $('#drop_2').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_2').fadeOut();
        setTimeout(\"finishAjax_tier_three('result_2', '\"+escape(response)+\"')\", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
</script>";
}

//**************************************
//     Second selection results     //
//**************************************
if (isset($_GET['func'])&& $_GET['func'] == "drop_2" ) {
drop_2($_GET['drop_var'], $_GET['drop_var2']);
}

function drop_2($drop_var, $drop_var2)
{  
    include_once('db.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT year FROM vehicles WHERE make='$drop_var' AND model='$drop_var2'") 
    or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<select name="drop_3" id="drop_3">
          <option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Selecteer Jaar</option>';

           while($drop_3 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_3['year'].'">'.$drop_3['year'].'</option>';
            }

    echo '</select>';
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$('#wait_3').hide();
    $('#drop_3').change(function(){
      $('#wait_3').show();
      $('#result_3').hide();
      $.get(\"func.php\", {
        func: \"drop_3\",
        drop_var: $('#drop_1').val(),
        drop_var2: $('#drop_2').val(),
        drop_var3: $('#drop_3').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_3').fadeOut();
        setTimeout(\"finishAjax_tier_four('result_3', '\"+escape(response)+\"')\", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
</script>";
}

//**************************************
//     Third selection results     //
//**************************************
if (isset($_GET['func'])&& $_GET['func'] == "drop_3" ) {
drop_3($_GET['drop_var'], $_GET['drop_var2'], $_GET['drop_var3']);
}

function drop_3($drop_var, $drop_var2, $drop_var3)
{  
    include_once('db.php');
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT color FROM vehicles WHERE make='$drop_var' AND model='$drop_var2' AND year='$drop_var3'") 
    or die(mysql_error());  

    echo '<select name="drop_4" id="drop_4">
          <option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Selecteer Kleur</option>';

           while($drop_4 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
            {
                if ($drop_4['color'] != "") {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_4['color'].'">'.$drop_4['color'].'</option>';
                }
            }

    echo '</select>';
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$('#wait_4').hide();
    $('#drop_4').change(function(){
      $('#wait_4').show();
      $('#result_4').hide();
      $.get(\"func.php\", {
        func: \"drop_4\",
        drop_var: $('#drop_1').val(),
        drop_var2: $('#drop_2').val(),
        drop_var3: $('#drop_3').val(),
        drop_var4: $('#drop_4').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_4').fadeOut();
        setTimeout(\"finishAjax_tier_five('result_4', '\"+escape(response)+\"')\", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
</script>";
}

//**************************************
//     Fourth selection results     //
//**************************************
if(isset($_GET['func'])&& $_GET['func'] == "drop_4" ) {
drop_4($_GET['drop_var'], $_GET['drop_var2'], $_GET['drop_var3'], $_GET['drop_var4']);
}
function drop_4($drop_var, $drop_var2, $drop_var3, $drop_var4)
{  
    include_once('db.php');
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE make='$drop_var' AND model='$drop_var2' AND year='$drop_var3' AND color='$drop_var4'") 
    or die(mysql_error());  



           while($drop_5 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
                {
                if ($drop_5['img'] != "") {
              echo '<input type="checkbox" name="drop_5" id="drop_5" style="display:none;" checked value="'.$drop_5['img'].'"/>';

                }
  }
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />';
}

?>
```

After I selected all my dropdown items and press submit it is working good but all the selected values are gone...

If you want to change color you have to go to the whole dropdown list again. Is it possible to keep all the selected values after submit?

Thanks in advance

Kind Regards

Joep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using GET requests to display each dropdown list in turn, and then using a POST request to submit your completed form. You should make sure that all the dropdowns are displayed after the POST request.

In index.php, I think you could try something like that :

```
<span id="result_1" style="display: none;">
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit']) {
            drop_1($_POST['drop_1']);
        }
    ?>
</span>

...

<span id="result_2" style="display: none;">
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit']) {
            drop_2($_POST['drop_1'], $_POST['drop_2']);
        }
    ?>
</span>

...

<span id="result_3" style="display: none;">
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit']) {
            drop_3($_POST['drop_1'], $_POST['drop_2'], $_POST['drop_3']);
        }
    ?>
</span>

etc...
```

Anyway, the idea is to reuse the functions that build your dropdowns, based on the values in the `$_POST`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... tried that but does not work... I cant even make the dropdowns stay after submit... Something is removing it after submit but I dont know what I have to change in the script to keep the dropdowns visible and keeping the selected value... trying the whole day to figure it out but no luck so far:(

Comment: I corrected my code a bit, that version should be closer to the solution... but I guess you had already corrected it ;) The "thing" that is removing your dropdowns after submit is simply that you're reloading the whole page, whereas when you select a value in a dropdown, only the next dropdown gets updated by an AJAX call. You could use the values of $_POST like I suggested, or you could make the submit button perform an AJAX call too, to update only the picture.

Comment: Thanks for the update!:) My dropdowns are visible after submit now but they dont remember the selected value... any ideas to fix that?:) If not thanks a lot for the help so far:D

Comment: In each of your drop_N functions, you need to write out `selected="selected"` in the HTML when the `<option>` you're writing matches the corresponding `$_POST['drop_N']` variable. For example in drop_3, you could write : `echo '<option value="'.$drop_3['year'].'"'.(isset($_POST['drop_3']) && $drop_3['year'] == $_POST['drop_3']) ? ' selected="selected"' : ''.'>'.$drop_3['year'].'</option>';`. Beware of bugs in my code, as I have no means to test it!